# SQL Server query select random rows with additional related rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get 200 random rows of SocialMedia_Question. Each row of SocialMedia_Question has related rows in SocialMedia_Answer.Content. In the result of the query, I want to see 200 random SocialMedia_Question.id and other columns that are specified in select.
(Problem is that each SocialMedia_Question.id has several numbers of related  SocialMedia_Answer.Content which makes the result of this query contains several rows for the same question.id)

I have tried select top and RAND()but couldn't make it work. I don't think simply select top 200 will work because I need 200 questions with all of their associated data in the result.

```sql
select 
    SocialMedia_Question.id as QuestionID, 
    SocialMedia_Question.Content as Question,
    SocialMedia_Question.CreatedBy as IDQuestionCreator,
    SocialMedia_Question.LikeCount as QuestionLikeCount,
    SocialMedia_Answer.Content as comment, 
    SocialMedia_Answer.createdby as IDCommenter
from  
    SocialMedia_User 
inner join 
    SocialMedia_Question on SocialMedia_Question.CreatedBy = SocialMedia_user.Id 
left join 
    SocialMedia_answer on SocialMedia_Question.id = SocialMedia_answer.QuestionId 
left join 
    SocialMedia_UserDeactivate on SocialMedia_user.id = SocialMedia_UserDeactivate.userid
where 
    ((SocialMedia_UserDeactivate.userid is null)
     and (exists (select null from SocialMedia_Question 
                  where SocialMedia_answer.CreatedBy = SocialMedia_Question.CreatedBy))
    and (SocialMedia_Question.AnswerCount > 10))
order by  
    SocialMedia_user.Id, SocialMedia_Answer.CreatedOn
```

I expect 200 random `SocialMedia_Question.id` rows in the result of the query in addition to all other columns specified in the select statement. I truly appreciate your help!

Comment: "I want to see all 200 random SocialMedia_Question.id".  If you are selecting all of them, what is random about it?

Comment: Haha my though exakt. But if your problem is that your are getting more then 200 rows then simple limit the data by adding `OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 200 ROWS ONLY;` after `order by `

Answer (score 0):

You can order a set by `NEWID()` and select `TOP 200` from `SocialMedia_Question`:

```
 select
    SocialMedia_Question.id as QuestionID, 
    SocialMedia_Question.Content as Question,
    SocialMedia_Question.CreatedBy as IDQuestionCreator,
    SocialMedia_Question.LikeCount as QuestionLikeCount,
    SocialMedia_Answer.Content as comment, 
    SocialMedia_Answer.createdby as IDCommenter
from  
    SocialMedia_User 
inner join 
    (select top 200 * FROM SocialMedia_Question order by NEWID()) AS SocialMedia_Question on SocialMedia_Question.CreatedBy = SocialMedia_user.Id 
left join 
    SocialMedia_answer on SocialMedia_Question.id = SocialMedia_answer.QuestionId 
left join 
    SocialMedia_UserDeactivate on SocialMedia_user.id = SocialMedia_UserDeactivate.userid
where 
    ((SocialMedia_UserDeactivate.userid is null)
     and (exists (select null from SocialMedia_Question 
                  where SocialMedia_answer.CreatedBy = SocialMedia_Question.CreatedBy))
    and (SocialMedia_Question.AnswerCount > 10))
```

Comment: i wanted to comment why not simply use `OVER()` instead off `OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))` as the documentation says `OVER (   
       [ <PARTITION BY clause> ]  
       [ <ORDER BY clause> ]   
       [ <ROW or RANGE clause> ]  
      )  `  which BNF means every option in the `OVER()` is optional untill i've [tryed](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1d72c/2) which is cleary contradictory with the manual..

Comment: But on the other hand it makes some logical sense to force `ORDER BY` when using `ROW_NUMBER()` you ideally would like to make sure you have a deterministic (fixed) result but still `OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))` would still not enforce deterministic results..

Comment: @M.Kanarkowski Thanks for your answer! select top 200 is selecting 200 rows that are in the top (not exactly 200 from Question table) right? So the result may not contain exactly 200 questions with their related answers and metadata.  Also, I get this error when trying your answer "Invalid column name 'NEWID'."

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks for your comments, could you please explain your point more?

Comment: @Aria I see your point. I edited the query, now you will get 200 random questions.

Comment: @M.Kanarkowski Thanks again! I tried it and I didn't get any error, but the result of the query is 0 rows! I think it is because of the where condition that filters from SocialMedia_Question. select top 200 * FROM SocialMedia_Question happens before the where condition.

Comment: @M.Kanarkowski I really appreciate it if you can answer my last comment!

Comment: @Aria Sorry, I haven't seen your data. You are right, if WHERE can eliminate rows from TOP 200 then this WHERE must me together with TOP clause.